# How to display an in-app notification that doesn't stick around in the notification drawer à la Snapchat

Tags: java, android, notifications, kotlin

So the idea is to present the user with a notification of some kind (doesn't have to be a standard Android notification, could be a library or custom) like Snapchat does. That is, it shows up in the app and then goes away without appearing in the status bar or notification drawer. Does any know of a way to do this with stock notifications or through a library? Or is this something I'd have to develop myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood, you want something like alerts, but it should looks like notifications:

https://github.com/Hamadakram/Sneaker

https://github.com/Tapadoo/Alerter

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!